# php global function or procedure

Tags: php, function, procedures

I have some php code which works to chek the incoming url and i have hundreds of php pages in which i have to chek the incoming url and i want to do make that code like a procedure or function which can be called in all php pages. So i can apply easily my code effect to all pages apparantly.Here is my php code

```
<?php
ob_start();
$domain = array("http://a.sml.com.pk/default.aspx","http://a.sml.com.pk/");
if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$domain))
{
$URL1="http://a.sml.com.pk"; 
header ("Location: $URL1");

}
else{

set_time_limit(500);
$url = 'http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptestsfpl&report=sales_milk';
$pdf = 'milksales.pdf';
$pdfbak = 'bak/'.$pdf;

if (filesize($pdf) > 10000)
{
copy($pdf,$pdfbak);
}

if ((int)time() > filemtime($pdf) + 30) 
{
file_put_contents($pdf, file_get_contents($url));
}
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

if (filesize($pdf) > 10000)
{
readfile($pdf);
}
else
{
readfile($pdfbak);
}
}
?>
```

Now I want to make procedure for this code which should be applied in all my files

```
ob_start();
    $domain = array("http://a.sml.com.pk/default.aspx","http://a.sml.com.pk/");
    if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$domain))
    {
    $URL1="http://a.sml.com.pk"; 
    header ("Location: $URL1");

    }
    else{
```

Please any one help me to convert my code before else portion into procedure and how that procedure will be called in all file regrding else portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test_referer()
{
    static $domain = array("http://a.sml.com.pk/default.aspx","http://a.sml.com.pk/");
    if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $domain)) {
        header ("Location: http://a.sml.com.pk");
        exit;
    }
}
```

In your code, you would call like:

```
test_referer();
// domain verified, continue your code
```

Comment: Ok Sir But I have hundreds of php files in which i have to chek the domain so may i have to write this function in all files or how to call this function in files

Comment: I would get: `The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.` as my referrer is always null

Comment: @user1353261 you can put the code inside `test_referer` into a separate .php file and then use .htaccess to always prepend it to all your scripts; see also http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-78287.html

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you're right; the redirect URL could contain a retry counter that increases until a limit is reached, after which a custom error page could be shown :)

Answer (score 2):

you can write below code in one php file like domainCheker.php

```
<?php
    $domain = array("http://a.sml.com.pk/default.aspx","http://a.sml.com.pk/");
    if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $domain)) 
    {
        header ("Location: http://a.sml.com.pk");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Now, include this php file in you all pages on starting, like

```
<?php
    include 'PATH_CHECK_DOMAIN';//  give the above file path 
?>
```

after you can start coding........!